# Problems with $.remove() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone

To put it simple...

I have element `clone`. Its `div` with some other tags saved in it. It also have `.x` in it.

I need to remove it and then apped that modified element to another element.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Remove failed or something, but `.x` is still in it.

```
clone = subtitle.clone(); // Works!
no_label = clone.remove('.x'); // This fails.
more_subtitles.append(no_label); // Its appends no_label, but it still contains .x element.
```

Comment: What is in your variable subtitle?

Comment: `subtitle` is another element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) removes the matched elements from the DOM. Even if you pass a selector, it's only used to filter these elements. In your code, `clone` matches a single element (the cloned subtitle) which doesn't expose the `x` class.

You can use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to match the `.x` element:

```
more_subtitles.append(subtitle.clone().find(".x").remove().end());
```

Answer (score 1):

remove() is for deleting elements. In order to remove a class you need to use removeClass(className).

Comment: No, no, no. I want to remove **element** with selector `.x` that's in element `clone`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to delete .x element from inside the clone?

```
 clone.find('.x').remove()
```

Comment: +1. http://api.jquery.com/remove/ The selector argument is used to filter the `clone` variable, not to select `clone`'s children elements. But this time `clone` might be a single element set and the element doesn't have class `x` so it fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
clone = subtitle.clone();
no_label = clone.find('.x').detach();
more_subtitles.append(clone);
```

Note that you can use `.detach()` instead of `.remove()`. This will hold onto any metadata attached to the element.

Comment: I don't know why is that so, but it removes **all** other element that that one that match `.x`. Funny!

Comment: That's because `.detach` returns the detached elements and the result is assigned to `no_label`. And the third statement appended `no_label` instead of `clone`. Changing it to `more_subtitles.append(clone);` will fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to remove a class from clone? If yes, then use removeClass as follows:

```
clone.removeClass('x');
```